# VBA download a File from OneDrive

Tags: vba, onedrive, office365api

I am trying to download a file from OneDrive. I am new to API Concepts and here is Code,

```
Sub OneDrive_Download()

'Declare the Object
Dim oRequest As Object

'Create and Assign Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'Input User OneDrive URL
URL = "https://xxxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/sidxxx_ie/"

'Post the URL in the Object
oRequest.Open "POST", URL, False

'Send Keys to the API
oRequest.send ("{""client_id"":myclientid,""CLIENT_SECRET"":myclientsecret}")


'Print the Response in the Immediate Window
 Debug.Print oRequest.ResponseText

 End Sub
```

And this is the Response that I got from Debug.Print on my Immediate window,

```
// Setup cta message fields.
window.$Do.when("User", 0, function ()
{
    User.setupCallToActionMessages();
});

// Other tile
var Tiles = Tiles || {};
Tiles.otherJSON = {
    'name': 'Use another account',
    'login': '',
    'imageAAD': 'other_glyph.png',
    'imageMSA': 'other_glyph.png',
    'isLive': false,
    'link': 'other',
    'authUrl': '',
    'sessionID': '',
    'domainHint': 'other'
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am looking to download a file named as test.xlsx in my OneDrive. What is the way to go about it.

**UPDATED - CODE**

```
Sub DownloadFile()

'Declare the Object and URL
Dim myURL As String
Dim WinHttpReq As Object

'Assign the URL and Object to Variables
myURL = "https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Sidxxx/Documents/test.xlsx"
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Provide Access Token and PWD to the URL for getting the service from API
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "abcdef", "12345"
WinHttpReq.send

Debug.Print WinHttpReq.Status

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then

        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        oStream.Open

        oStream.Type = 1

        oStream.SaveToFile "C:\testdownload.xlsx", 2

        oStream.Close

    End If

End Sub
```

The file is now getting downloaded. But it appears to be empty.

Comment: `oRequest.Open "GET", URLofFile, False` I would think. I don't know what the false is for though.

Comment: Doesn't OneDrive get mapped to a drive letter on your computer? If it does, you should be able to use regular file commands to copy a file from it to your PC.

Comment: @RichHolton yes, It is mapped in to my local. But the application needs to download the file from shared with me folder. That's where the problem begins. OneDrive doesn't sync the shared files to the local and sync.

Comment: @Sid29: Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: @GibralterTop No. It didn't help. I tried that as well.

Comment: @RichHolton No problem !

Comment: Are you sure you're authenticating correctly? Your response says `Use another account`

Comment: @GibralterTop Yes Sir ! I am able to now download the file but its coming as empty. I will update the code now. Just see if you can help on that.

Comment: try adding `oStream.Flush` after you `SaveToFile` typically `.Flush` sends all bytes to your response stream. Might be why it's an empty file.

Comment: @GibralterTop No Sir. Not working with Flush. But I got it to work. I was missing this line in my code -  oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me. Thanks everyone for your advice.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

'Declare the Object and URL
Dim myURL As String
Dim WinHttpReq As Object

'Assign the URL and Object to Variables
myURL = "https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Sidxxx/Documents/test.xlsx"
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Provide Access Token and PWD to the URL for getting the service from API
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "abcdef", "12345"
WinHttpReq.send

Debug.Print WinHttpReq.Status

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then

        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        oStream.Open

        oStream.Type = 1

         oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody

        oStream.SaveToFile "C:\testdownload.xlsx", 2

        oStream.Close

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is Access Token and PWD your email address and password to login?