# Unable to connect to Excel file in OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I've been searching and searching but with no luck.  Is there a way to use Excel VBA to import master file data from another excel workbook saved in OneDrive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**A.)**      If you have an excel workbook that is **stored locally on your PC** but inside your OneDrive sync-ed folder.Then you can use following VBA code to approach one drive file. Once file is available there are many routines already on *SO* to import data.

```
Sub Test()
Dim fn As String
fn = "Your File " 'change file name

fn = Environ("onedrive") & "\" & fn

'check to see if it exists
If Len(fn) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print fn
End If
'... do something.......
End Sub
```

**B.)**     **FETCH FILES** If you have the OneDrive desktop app for Windows installed on a PC, you can use the Fetch files feature to access all your files on that PC from another computer by going to the OneDrive website. You can even access network locations if they're included in the PC's libraries or mapped as drives. When you browse a PC's files remotely, you can download copies of them to work on. You can also stream video and view photos in a slide show. To access files on your PC remotely, make sure the PC you want to access is turned on and connected to the Internet. OneDrive also needs to be running on that PC, and the Fetch files setting must be selected. For further Details please refer [Fetch files on your PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fetch-files-on-your-pc-70761550-519c-4d45-b780-5a613b2f8822)

**C.) FIle on ShareOint - VBA aopproach**  If your file is on SharePoint. OneDrive doesn't sync the shared files to the local and sync. In such case VBA code is available on SO [VBA download a File from OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848083/vba-download-a-file-from-onedrive) by @Sid29

**D.)REST APIs - Microsoft Graph**     Another situation is elaborated in the following paragraph which uses API.

> The OneDrive REST API is a portion of the Microsoft Graph API which
>   allows your app to connect to content stored in OneDrive and
>   SharePoint. The REST API is shared between OneDrive, OneDrive for
>   Business, SharePoint document libraries, and Office Groups, to allow
>   your app the flexibility to read and store content in any of these
>   locations with the same code.

These REST APIs are a part of the Microsoft Graph, a common API for Microsoft services.

For existing solutions using OneDrive API outside of Microsoft Graph, or solutions targeting SharePoint Server 2016, see direct endpoint differences for more context on reading this documentation. [OneDrive and SharePoint in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online)

**E.)**      It may be difficult to get url of specific online file of onedrive. Microsoft Community has covered a situation where they have suggested VBA code for downloading of a file without URL.It is  report xlsx from a web application.
Because the URL isn't the path to the file, it's a 'file request link' it processes single sign on verification, then the download popup is displayed.
Though it depends on the web site , code mentioned in article executed successfully using IE browser. Code mentioned in [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8099c4f9-4383-4c63-a96f-f5d5aa8c8e19/vba-to-download-a-file-without-a-direct-url?forum=isvvba) can be experimented with. There is no other method to load online onedrive file through VBA in my knowledge.